# Upload an image, then make it resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to upload an image then display on screen while it's draggable and resizable. I'm using jquery for the draggable and resizable functions. The problem is, the draggable function works, but the resizable function ruins something and the uploaded image doesn't appear.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="block">
  <div id="background">
    <img id="bg" class="block-add" src="" alt="" width="auto" height="50%" />
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#bg')
          .attr('src', e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#bg").draggable(); //this one always works
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#bg").resizable(); //this one doesn't work with the uploader script
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try wrapping it inside `div`  like this   then call draggable & resizable on that element**

you just need initial src for setup properties change it  as you like

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this)" accept="image/*" />
<div class="block">
  <div id="background">
    <DIV id='bg_container'>
      <img id="bg" class="block-add" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" alt="" />
    </DIV>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#bg')
          .attr('src', e.target.result);

      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bg_container").draggable();
    $("#bg").resizable();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The image doesn't appear with this. And also the draggable function doesn't work with this.

Comment: Oh u edited it. I see it's working here, but I'm copying your code and my image still doesn't appear. Like what...?

Comment: try now everything works  ,  don't forget accepting the answer 